# Compile stylus with VueCLI 3

Tags: vuetify.js, stylus, vue-cli-3

I've tried a couple of setups in the vue.config.js to get the VueCLI to compile a .stylus file (for use with Vuetify). But so far nothing worked.

What's the proper way to let VueCLI compile the .stylus files along with the reset of my files? (I'm using TypeScript in case that would make any difference).

Comment: You do have  stylus and  stylus-loader in your devDependencies, right?

Comment: Yes, all of it.. I just need some example code of what to put in the vue.config.js for example